# placing nesting ul's to the right

Tags: html, css

I am currently building a custom navigation dropdown, for that I would like to place the ul that is wrapped by a parent li next to its parent.

The navigation will have a border around the first level, which should contain the other Levels as well. 
Positioning the ul absolute to the next level ul does kind of work, but not as requested. Fiddle at the bottom.

```
Default view:

- Level 1
- Level 1
    - Level 2
        - Level 3
        - Level 3
    - Level 2
    - Level 2
    - Level 2
- Level 1

Desired output:

- Level 1    - Level 2    - Level 3
- Level 1    - Level 2    - Level 3
- Level 1    - Level 2
             - Level 2

Example:

-------------------------------
| Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 |
| Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 |
| Level 1 | Level 2 |         |
|         | Level 2 |         |
-------------------------------
```

---

Basic syntax:

```
<ul>
    <li>Level 1</li>
    <li>
        Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>
                Level 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1</li>
</ul>
```

**[Minified current solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Gr/w8oe59rp/)**

Comment: Out of interest, why are you having all the results appear? If it's a drop-down surely you only want those below the selected item to appear.

Comment: Do you need it with a dynamic height? With a fixed height you can use this: http://jsfiddle.net/w8oe59rp/2/

Comment: I am still clueless about his query :D :D and I don't know how people answering :P

Comment: Am I right in thinking that all you're wanting is the height of all the levels containers to be the same? And am I correct in thinking you cannot change the DOM structure?

Comment: @JamieBarker Exactly, sorry if this seems to be quite a bit confusing. Absolute positioning doesnt expand the main container in the Level 1 `ul` which gives me a quite hard time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is impossible without using JavaScript or amending the DOM structure.

What you want it to do is to remove layout so all the `LI` sit next to each other, however you also want to keep it so the height of the whole container is kept.

So, here's a working JavaScript solution: http://jsfiddle.net/w8oe59rp/8/

```js
var arrUL = document.querySelectorAll('ul'),
    MaxHeight = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arrUL.length; i++) {
    var intHeight = arrUL[i].offsetHeight;
    if (intHeight > MaxHeight) {
        MaxHeight = intHeight;   
    }
}
document.querySelector('.main').style.height = MaxHeight + 'px'
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    width: 15em;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
li {
    width: 5em;
}
.main {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.main:before {
    content:"";
    border-left:1px solid;
    top:0;
    left:33.33%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
.main:after {
    content:"";
    border-left:1px solid;
    top:0;
    right:33.33%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
ul ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:33.33%;
    width:5em;
}
ul ul ul {
    left:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
    <li>Level 1</li>
    <li>Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>Level 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give child ul to position relative.
here is working demp

```css
.container {
    height: 117px;
    position: relative;
}
ul{
    bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

li{
    width: 5em;
}

.main{
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}

.main > li ul {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="main">
    <li>Level 1</li>
    <li>
        Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>
                Level 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                    <li>Level 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
            <li>Level 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Level 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The lists in your solution drop below the container, a fixed height on the container wont help because the ul is absolute. Still I thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
li ul{
    display: none;
}

li:hover{
    background-color: limegreen;
}/*just for styling*/

li:hover > ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Edit ul padding

```
padding: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
```

jsfiddle link -> http://jsfiddle.net/w8oe59rp/3/

**Edit**

add class `has-dropdown` to any `li` that has drop down and then add this style

```
.has-dropdown{
    position: relative;
}
.has-dropdown ul{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Updated fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/w8oe59rp/4/

Comment: Hiding and displaying the lower levels is not a problem, sorry

Comment: Sorry I must misunderstood. I edited my answer. is this what you need?

Comment: No sorry. Basically the lower levels should be part of the highest level container. If youre able to put a border to the upper `ul` that contains all lower levels it would be perfect, but I'm not quite sure if/how that would work, at least without js magic

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get what you mean. Can you attach an image or something to make it clear for me?

Comment: Here, it should look like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex_Gr/8Lkmw13f/2/)